# How do you prevent an input type=submit from closing a modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a modal that contains a form

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name"
        value="<?php echo $_SESSION['post-data']['name']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email"
        value="<?php echo $_SESSION['post-data']['email']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Your Comment:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="comment"><?php echo $_SESSION['post-data']['comment']; ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

The PHP runs fine when the submit button is pressed and emails are sending.

The PHP

```
<?php

  $_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;

        if ($_POST["submit"]) {



             if (!$_POST['name']) {

                $error="<br />Please enter your name";

             }

             if (!$_POST['email']) {

                $error.="<br />Please enter your email address";

             }

             if (!$_POST['comment']) {

                 $error.="<br />Please enter a comment";

            }

             if ($_POST['email']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'],
                FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                 $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address";

             }

             if ($error) {

                 $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s)
                in your form:</strong>'.$error.'</div>';

         } else {

            if (mail("myemail", "Comment from website", "Name: ".
            $_POST['name']."

             Email: ".$_POST['email']."

            Comment: ".$_POST['comment'])) 

            {
             $result='<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank
            you!</strong> I\'ll be in touch.</div>';

            unset($_SESSION['post-data']['name']);

            unset($_SESSION['post-data']['email']);

            unset($_SESSION['post-data']['comment']);

         } else {

            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, there was
            an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';

        }

     }
 }

 ?>
```

however I would like the Modal to remain open after the submit button is clicked.  I have searched all over SO and most related questions suggest using

```
**data-backdrop="static"**
```

but that has not worked.  I believe it may be because it is an input and not a button but I am not sure.

Comment: There's only really one way to submit a form and not redirect, and it's called Ajax.

Comment: I agree on what @adeneo suggested

Answer (score 1):

you could either use ajax, then you submit without redirecting, and get the result data and do whatever you want with it.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

the other thing you could do is to use javascript to open the modal if a post is there on the file. basically echo a javascript command that would open the modal again.